# jQuery filter on internal HTML of tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a working search box on the page.  the goal is to hide any LI item that does not match the current search string.  However, the list is being created with a calendar-framework function that also includes City information on the same line as the venue name what I want to find.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#search").keyup(function()
    {
        // capture the current user search input, and create a RegEx for comparison
        var searchString = $.trim(this.value);
        var searchRegEx = new RegExp(searchString, "ig");

        // Begin evaluating the user input once the 3rd character is inputted
        if(searchString.length < 3)
        {
            // Otherwise make sure all records are displayed
            $('li').show();
        }
        else
        {
            // Hide all of the records
            $('li').hide();

            // Filter a list of records that match RegEx from user input, and then display
            $('li').filter(function()
            {
                return this.innerHTML.match(searchRegEx);
            }).show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the function call that is tied to the INPUT TEXTBOX.  Below is an example of what I am trying to show/hide.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://somewebsite/path/index.php?com=location&amp;lID=154">American Royal</a> | <span>Kansas City</span>
    </li>

    <li><a href="http://somewebsite/path/index.php?com=location&amp;lID=155">Ameristar Casino Hotel Kansas City</a> | <span>Kansas City</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

'Ameri' should display both, while 'American' would only return one value.  Those search strings work; however, if someone types 'Kansas' it shows both rather than just the 2nd record.

I have successfully been able to capture just the A tag HTML, but the match(searchRegEx) doesn't seem to work like I expected.

Comment: I don't understand why you've put the urls in there or is this just spam? Excuse me if you're legit!

Comment: I'm sorry about the URL.  I should have taken them out.  They are just from a copy-paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What can't you just filter in the `a` tag?  Note that `this` should be `$(this)` to use jQuery functions.  And the jQuery version of `innerHTML` is `.html()`.

```
$('li').filter(function()
{
    return $(this).find('a').first().html().match(searchRegEx);
}).show();
```

Or:

```
$('li').filter(function()
{
    return $(this).children('a').first().html().match(searchRegEx);
}).show();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/28dbd286/

Comment: I'm not sure.  I have been able to grab the innerHTML from that firstChild, but whatever i'm passing back up to the filter().show() doesn't work

Comment: Ah, you are mixing and matching jQuery and standard javascript calls. `this` is not a jQuery object, but `$(this)` is.  Also `innerHTML` is standard javascript, not jQuery.  You could use it, after retrieving the DOM object, but `.html()` is simpler.  See edits above.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is great, but I must be missing something on my side when trying to match the functionality.  JSFiddle is exactly what I want.  Right now once I hit the ELSE statement it hides everything, but nothing gets shown that matches

Comment: I think my issue my have something to do with the navigation LI items elsewhere on the page.  Could I just set the venue list inside a P tag with an ID that I select first?

Comment: Use some `console.log` messages to see what's going on.  The fact that all of the `li`'s get hidden suggests my code should work.  Double check the return line against mine.

Comment: I had the right idea last night.  My code was mixing JS and JQuery, but looked about the same.  I made a change to me code and created a JQuery object for the elements I wanted.  This was selected first as the element that matchd `class=locations` and then called the `children('li')` to populate the variable.  it works perfectly now.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You dont need regex for that. You can just check if the searchstring is in the other string with:

```
if (myString.indexOf("America") >= 0)
...
```

Or if it should be case insensitive

```
if (myString.toLowerCase().indexOf(mysearchstring.toLowerCase) >= 0) {
....
```

Comment: I agree. using `indexOf` here seems like a best bet. However, it also seems like the OP doesn't want to match text after the pipe `|` so let's split it on that too. `myString.split('|')[0].indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase) >=0`